# How can I make an area accessible only by certain ranks with the Minecraft PowerRanks plugin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

My server is a gens server. (A gens server is basically only known from Minefort server hosting) and I need an area where only a couple of ranks can enter.

These ranks are ranks defined from the PowerRanks plugin for Minecraft: [Powerranks Website](https://powerranks.nl/)

Any Ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would advise that you include important information about those ranks in your question, especially since your link itself doesn't even give information about ranks. Please include what ranks are, and how they can be used in commands.

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797) — especially the part about "what you've tried so far."